# Is the foliage which is separated from a plant still called foliage?

Tags: word-meaning

I understand "*foliage*" can mean the leaves which grow on a plant.

I'd like to find out if "*foliage*" can mean the leaves falling from a plant. For this purpose, I made up the following sentences:
**(1a)** *The wind was whirling falling **leaves***. — I think it's correct
**(1b)** *The wind was whirling falling **foliage***. — is it correct?

I'd like to find out if "*foliage*" can mean the leaves fallen from a plant. For this purpose, I made up the following sentences:
**(2a)** *The path was covered in fallen **leaves***. — I think it's correct
**(2b)** *The path was covered in fallen **foliage***. — is it correct?

Comment: It sounds rather pretentious when 'leaves' is a perfectly good word.

Comment: @KateBunting But is it correct? Loviii might want to be pretentious.

Comment: @gotube - I'm not sure. All the examples I found use _foliage_ with reference to growing leaves _en masse_, or decorative representations of leafy branches, but I can't prove that it's incorrect for fallen leaves.